# sp_executeSQL and Statment with more than 2000 characters

Tags: sql-server, procedures, sp-executesql

I'm using dynamic SQL and I need to exec a long SQL query, First I declare @var with query as nvarchar(4000), but my query is longer than 4000 chars.
I try to change to nvarchar(8000) but raise an Exception that can't be longer than 4000 chars.

Finally I declare var as varchar(8000) and no error ocurrs , but when I going to exe sp_executeSQL
raise and error that sp_executeSQL expect a ntext/nchar/nvarchar.

How I can exec a longer Sql Query with sp_executeSQL ?
Thnks!

I'm using Sql Server Express 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are on 2005 you can use `declare @var nvarchar(max)` for up to 1 billion characters.

You will find using `PRINT` statements doesn't work to view the variable contents for very long strings so you can do

```
SELECT @var AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

To see the untruncated contents.

Comment: This is THE answer for debugging dynamic sql!  Thank you so much.  I found another answer that used a similar XML approach, but the output was encoded (e.g. "<>" would appear as "lt;gt;").  Your approach does not have that problem AND I can view the dynamic code with line-breaks (instead of it jumbled into one long line).